# :erlang.list_to_atom("roster") error when accessing mnesia table

Tags: erlang, elixir, ejabberd, mnesia

I am trying get `mnesia` table info from elixir shell.

I have tried to convert the string to atom.

```
String.to_atom("roster")
```

I have tried to pass string as list `["roster"]`

command -

```
:ejabberd_admin.mnesia_table_info("roster")
```

error

```
ArgumentError
:erlang.list_to_atom("roster")
```

Answer (score 5):

Erlang expects a charlist there, not a binary. Use *single quotes*:

```
:ejabberd_admin.mnesia_table_info('roster')
```

Also: [`Kernel.to_charlist/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#to_charlist/1), [`~c/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_c/2).

---

Documentation on charlists on [official site](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#charlists).

---

*Example:*

```
iex(1)> :erlang.list_to_atom("roster")
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.list_to_atom("roster")
iex(1)> :erlang.list_to_atom('roster')
:roster
```

Comment: Yes, I do know how to join erlang nodes.

Comment: Can u please share the steps on this stack overflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202845/clustering-ejabberd-nodes-on-aws-ec2-instances